# python convert py to exe in ubuntu that work on windows

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, exe, executable

i am using ubuntu and i have a python program i want to change py to exe

that works for windows how can i do it

i tried

```
pyinstaller --onefile g_long.py
```

but when i run the file can not run on windows

so is there any command or any other solution

i know there is another command which is **autopy** but i think it will convert to its operating system if i run on windows it will work for windows if i run on linux it will work for linux

Comment: [This may help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739562/how-do-i-create-a-windows-executable-with-pyinstaller-on-ubuntu). In brief, you cannot generate Windows executables with pyinstaller on Ubuntu.

Comment: now i know it is not working with pyinstaller any other idea

Comment: What you want to do is *cross-compile*.  As @ DYZ says, `pyinstaller` can't do that. You need to run `pyinstaller` on a Windows machine to make a Windows executable.